# How to do minimize window in WPF, when user drag window from the top?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I implemented a custom window in WPF. It is possible to drag this window. So when i drag it to the top it maximizes. But than, when I drag this from the top, it should minimize - but it's not.

It is able to drag, but size is the same as maximize.

I'm looking for event which is called, when user drag window from maximize state, so i could call minimize function from code.

I can't find this event. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you leave this kind of functionality up to Windows? Windows 7 will handle most such gestures automatically (such as maximizing when dragging it to the top, cascading when dragging it to the side, etc).

What you want to achieve, however, is not standard behavior and I have never seen a program behave like that ever.

I would ask myself this: Is this really a functionality I want? Personally I would not do this unless there are very good reasons to do so

Comment: The behaviour he describes is the normal behaviour with win 7, so there either is a setting wrong in win 7 or the interaction doesn't fully work due to some of his code.

Comment: No, Windows 7 does not minimize a maximized window when you drag it. It puts it in a normal state

Comment: I think that's what he means, considering he describes the size after dragging "[as] the same as maximize".

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, i got hung up on the several 'minimize'-es in there :)

Comment: I know that Win7 do this max a min stuff. But Why It does only maximize and min not? What bothers me, at start window has "max" icon (to maximize). Than, when I drag it to the top (to maximize), icon change to min. And when I drag it to normal state (still has max size), it still has "min" icon, like it was maximize :/ BTW. In normal WPF window (like in widows os) - this operations works fine. I mean size, min/max icons etc.. When I created my own custom window, I do my own min/max, close icons, drag events etc... But this one drives me crazy:)

Comment: BTW. My bad.. as "minimize" I meant back to the normal state. Sorry:/